# Get Blackberry UID or device specific info

Tags: blackberry, guid, uid

Is there any way to get the UID of a Blackberry device using Javascript requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about with Javascript, but maybe [this](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/browser/Browser.html) helps from the Blackberry Java API.